# Content-type using axios

Tags: axios

I'm working with React and axios. I'm trying to fetch the response using axios however, unable to understand why I'm getting wrong `content-type` even though I'm setting it in my backend code.

Code (backend):

```
router.get(url, async (req, res) => {
  // return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    if (file exists) {
      var fileContents = Buffer.from(document[0].data, "base64"); //document contains the data from the postgres database 
      var readStream = new stream.PassThrough();
      readStream.end(fileContents);
      res.set(
        "Content-disposition",
        "attachment; filename=" + document[0].fileName
      );

      res.setHeader("content-type", document[0].fileType);
      readStream.pipe(res);

      console.log("+++++++++++++++++++");
      console.log(res);
      console.log("+++++++++++++++++++");

      return;
    } else {
      res.json({
        status: 0,
        message: "File not found",
      });
      return;
    }
    // resolve({ document });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

The above backend code works absolutely fine. I even printed the response to check whether the content-type is setting or not. I'm even providing the output snippet for that as well
[image]

However, in the frontend if I try to fetch the response this is what I'm receiving
[image]

I'm not sure what's wrong. Why I'm receiving wrong content-type. Even the content length is same for any sort of file which I try to download.

The axios call :

```
    let response = await Axios.get(fileURL, {
      responseType: "blob"/"arraybuffer",
      Authorization: "Bearer  " + token,
    });
```

Response.data output :

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the axios request code?

Comment: Can you share what `response.data` looks like?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan added the output snippet of response.data as well.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?